# React map gl with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapbox-gl-js

Hello so I'm fairly new to React, but I have made the choice of going through typescript (which I'm also new too) as opposed to raw JS. Having said that Im having trouble adding layers to a react-map-gl element.
Here is the error code that I'm getting

```
Type '{ id: string; type: string; paint: { 'sky-type': string; 'sky-atmosphere-sun': number[]; 'sky-atmosphere-sun-intensity': number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'LayerProps'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"symbol" | "sky" | "circle" | "line" | "fill" | "fill-extrusion" | "raster" | "background" | "heatmap" | "hillshade"'.ts(2322)
```

Which looks lke it says that it wants an enum?
Here are the offeding pieces of code:

```
const skyLayer = {
    id: 'sky',
    type: 'sky',
    paint: {
      'sky-type': 'atmosphere',
      'sky-atmosphere-sun': [0.0, 0.0],
      'sky-atmosphere-sun-intensity': 15
    }
  };
```

and this one which is the one that gives me red squigglies (under Layer):

```
<Layer {...skyLayer} />
```

And the sample code that I'm trying to follow:
https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/blob/6.1-release/examples/terrain/src/app.js

EDIT1: I changed things as suggested in the code but I cant seem to fix the issue. Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Type '{ id: string; type: "sky"; paint: { "sky-type": string; "sky-atmosphere-sun": number[]; "sky-atmosphere-sun-intensity": number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'LayerProps'.
  Types of property 'paint' are incompatible.
    Type '{ "sky-type": string; "sky-atmosphere-sun": number[]; "sky-atmosphere-sun-intensity": number; }' is not assignable to type 'BackgroundPaint | FillPaint | FillExtrusionPaint | LinePaint | SymbolPaint | RasterPaint | CirclePaint | HeatmapPaint | HillshadePaint'.
      Type '{ "sky-type": string; "sky-atmosphere-sun": number[]; "sky-atmosphere-sun-intensity": number; }' has no properties in common with type 'HillshadePaint'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem here but with "paint"

Answer (score 5):

You should decalre data type for `type` when you declare `skyLayer`. Because the default `type` will be string and can' be pass into `Layer`. You can use `as` to do it:

```
  const skyLayer = {
    id: 'sky',
    type: 'sky' as 'sky',
    paint: {
      'sky-type': 'atmosphere',
      'sky-atmosphere-sun': [0.0, 0.0],
      'sky-atmosphere-sun-intensity': 15
    }
  };
```

Comment: It did seem to work but there seems to be an error here: (EDIT1)

Answer (score 0):

You should import `SkyLayer` as a type from react-map-gl.

```js
import type {SkyLayer} from 'react-map-gl';
const skyLayer:SkyLayer = {
    id: 'sky',
    type: 'sky',
    paint: {
      'sky-type': 'atmosphere',
      'sky-atmosphere-sun': [0.0, 0.0],
      'sky-atmosphere-sun-intensity': 15
    }
  };
```

Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/blob/master/examples/terrain/src/app.tsx).